# Opening files in tabs in Macvim

Tags: macvim, nerdtree

I am using Macvim with Janus build. I have installed it just now. I have opened a project by

```
mvim <project-name>
```

But problem is that while I am double clicking a file on left hand side project explorer window, it keep on opening in the same window overriding the earlier opened file. But I want, while I double click a file it should open in a new tab.

So I am asking if anyone can help me to fix that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

NERDTree opens files in a new buffer because you are supposed to use tabs in vim in a different way. You might want to read :help buffers